# Cuando inicio mi terminal en MacOS High Sierra 10.12.6 obtengo "No such file or directory"

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

Cuando inicio mi terminal en MacOS High Sierra 10.12.6 estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
Restored session: Dom 21 Mar 2021 12:19:28 -03
-bash: `/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin: No such file or directory`
MacBook-Pro-de-Miguel:local miguelsantisteban$
```

Alguien sabe como corregirlo?
Eso sucedió después de instalar el Homebrew; ya lo desinstalé pero el error continua.
Mi carpeta /usr/local se muestra en la imagen:

[image: Carpeta /usr/local en MacOS High Sierra 10.12.6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tendrias que abrir el directorio `/usr/local/opt/` estas mostrando el local,antes de seguir ¿has hecho un `source ~/.bash_profile`?, si todo esta correcto verifica que este bien hecho el `export Path ="rutas"`  dentro del fichero `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Cuando entro a mi directorio ***/usr/local/opt/*** esta vacío.

Comment: y cuando entro `source ~/.bash_profile` me aparece lo siguiente:

`-bash: /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/php72/7.1.31_20190811-210031/bin:/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin: No such file or directory`

Comment: verifica el fichero ~/.bashprofile y localiza la linea `export Path=/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin` borra SOLO esta parte `/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:` ya que esta vacío y por eso te salta ese error.

Comment: Sí perfecto; eliminé ese error. Muchas gracias! Era ese el problema realmente. Eliminar las rutas que no estaban en el directorio /usr/local. Te lo agradezco mucho!